# Double fixture fitting with a cap on top

Tags: toilet, drain, vent

I'm looking to put two toilet drains into the vertical main from either side. I see that I should use a double wye fitting (according to everything I could find for toilets), but I cant find any examples of these being used without the top being a vent. This image shows what I want to do. Is this ok? If not, then what fitting would be better to use?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the building inspector, the original diagram is ok to do, but he recommended I go with a different system. This is what we came up with. Note: not included in this sketch are the vents for the vanities and showers. This is a crude representation of the system. Though they are simply getting AAVs. So, to answer my original question, yes you can use a double wye that way as long as the pipes are vented before that point. One other thing to note is that I got a photo of the wrong tee fitting, so it looks like the toilet drain is reduced. If you want to know why I spelled toilet incorrectly, do a google search for "letterkenny torlet" and enjoy.[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your update!